# How to create a barplot in R with multiple layers in the X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to replicate this barplot in R with the following table as the input data.
There are many other sites, other than CAV1, this is just a small example of the data.

```
  Site Time Abundance   Group        STDEV
1 CAV1 DAY0  7.15e-06   X            1.968384e-06
2 CAV1 Day1  3.39e-06   X            4.934761e-07
5 CAV2 DAY0  7.15e-07   Y            8.636959e-07
6 CAV2 Day1  3.39e-07   Y            3.511951e-07
```

[image]

Unfortunately, I have not found any codes to establish multiple values for the x-axis yet.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Time, y=Abundance, fill=Site)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
    theme_minimal()
```

I think some modifications to this simple plot call could help get me started in the right direction. 
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The graph you show looks like it might be using `Group`, not `Site` for the fill color. It's not clear what additional variables you want on the x-axis. Are there additional `Site` values that you don't include in your sample data or graph? If so, perhaps `facet_grid(Site ~ .)` or `facet_wrap(~Site)` is what you want?

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas yes there are other sites. I did not include them to make the example simpler.

Comment: I think then it's an oversimplification. It makes it seem like all you want is the label `"CAV1"`, and you get an answer like Duck's that addresses that, and exactly match the desired output you show, but I'm guessing leaves your actual problem unsolved. I'd strongly recommend editing your example data to include a couple rows with `Site = "CAV2"`.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I have added this to make my question clearer.

Comment: @Gregor, I have updated the answer for the edited question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: This question now answers the original question data and the edited question data.

---

You almost have it. You just need to change the `fill` aesthetic to Group and change your `position` argument:

```
library(ggplot2)

# for the original question data
df <- data.frame("Site" = rep("CAV1", 8),
                 "Time" = rep(c("DAY0", "DAY1", "DAY3", "DAY7"), 2),
                 "Abundance" = c(7.15e-06, 3.39e-06, 6.04e-07, 6.39e-07,
                                 6.64e-06, 5.59e-06, 2.55e-06, 1.01e-06),
                 "Group" = c(rep("X", 4), rep("Y", 4)),
                 "STDEV" = c(1.968384e-06, 4.934761e-07, 2.004625e-07, 2.020505e-07,
                             8.636959e-07, 3.511951e-07, 3.008267e-07, 3.01e-07))

# you can use this plot to have side-by-side bars for each group for each day
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Time, y=Abundance, fill=Group)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position="dodge") +
        theme_minimal()
```

[image]

This data only had one Site category, when we add more sites, we can facet by them:

```
# for the edited question data
df2 <- data.frame("Site" = c(rep("CAV1", 2), rep("CAV2", 2)),
                 "Time" = rep(c("DAY0", "DAY1"), 2),
                 "Abundance" = rep(c(7.15e-06, 3.39e-06), 2),
                 "Group" = c(rep("X", 2), rep("Y", 2)),
                 "STDEV" = c(1.968384e-06, 4.934761e-07, 8.636959e-07,  3.511951e-07))

# you can use this plot to additionally facet by the site
ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=Time, y=Abundance, fill=Group)) +
        facet_wrap(Site ~ .) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position="dodge") +
        theme_minimal()
```

[image]

However, in the edited data the Site and Group variables are perfectly correlated. The below example data and code more closely reflects the desired output plot from your edited question:

```
# for this data
df3 <- data.frame("Site" = c(rep("CAV1", 4), rep("CAV2", 4)),
                  "Time" = rep(c("DAY0", "DAY1"), 4),
                 "Abundance" = c(7.15e-06, 3.39e-06, 6.04e-07, 6.39e-07,
                                 6.64e-06, 5.59e-06, 2.55e-06, 1.01e-06),
                 "Group" = rep(c(rep("X", 2), rep("Y", 2)), 2),
                 "STDEV" = c(1.968384e-06, 4.934761e-07, 2.004625e-07, 2.020505e-07,
                             8.636959e-07, 3.511951e-07, 3.008267e-07, 3.01e-07))

# you can use the same code
ggplot(data=df3, aes(x=Time, y=Abundance, fill=Group)) +
        facet_wrap(Site ~ .) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position="dodge") +
        theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: This did answer what I posted but my question was misleading, I meant to have multiple 'Sites'. I have edited the query.

Comment: @Krutik I'd accept this answer, and try to use Gregor's suggestion of adding facet_wrap or facet_grid to your plot.

Comment: @Krutik, please see the updated answer. It uses Gregor's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use this:

```
library(ggplot2)
DF <- structure(list(Site = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "CAV1", class = "factor"), Time = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("DAY0", "Day1", "Day3", 
"Day7"), class = "factor"), Abundance = c(7.15e-06, 3.39e-06, 
6.04e-07, 6.39e-07, 6.64e-06, 5.59e-06, 2.55e-06, 1.01e-06), 
    Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("X", 
    "Y"), class = "factor"), STDEV = c(1.968384e-06, 4.934761e-07, 
    2.004625e-07, 2.020505e-07, 8.636959e-07, 3.511951e-07, 3.008267e-07, 
    3.01e-07)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))

#Plot
ggplot(data=DF, aes(x=Time, y=Abundance, fill=Group)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())+
    theme_minimal()+ labs(x = "CAV1")
```

[image]

Comment: This did answer what I posted but my question was misleading, I meant to have multiple 'Sites'. I have edited the query.